Having an issue where a computer keeps turning off Memory Integrity
Having an issue where a computer keeps turning off Memory Integrity
Having an issue where a computer keeps turning off Memory Integrity in Core Isolation on Windows 11
I am able to turn it back on without any issues.
Once I reboot after turning it on it works fine the whole day. But if i Turn the computer off and back on or reboot it, it is turned off again and I have to reactivate it.
I do not see any indication of what is causing this in the event logs either.
I took a suggestion from another forum to turn off virtualization in BIOS, reboot, then turn it back on. At first I thought it worked, but i tested starting the computer back up and it went back to turning off Memory Integrity again.
Any suggestions on where else to look for a possible answer to why this is happening?
Dell Xps 15 9530
64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-13900H 2.60 GHz
32.0 GB (31.7 GB usable)
